# 8 runners win race, specific person must be among top 3, combinations

Tags: combinatorics

> In a race with 30 runners where 8 trophies will be given to the top 8
>   runners (the trophies are distinct: first place, second place, etc)
>   (...)
>
> How many ways can you hand the trophies if a certain person, Ram, must
>   be one of the top 3 winners?

I did:
$$(3*2*1)*^{27}P_5$$

3 being the 3 positions Ram can occupy and $^{27}P_5$ the combinations of the remaining positions

Is this correct? If not, what did I do wrong?

Thanks

Comment: if "ram" is the first place then the number of the ways is $\frac{29!}{7!}$, but if "ram" is in the second place the number of the ways is the same, then the total number of the ways is $3\frac{29!}{7!}$

Comment: It is hard to tell you where you went wrong if you don't explain your thoughts..

Comment: @testpilot Right, I understand now. By the way, Ram is not really a "ram", I took this question from an Indian website.

Comment: @Lovsovs I already know the answer, but I will edit my question for future reference, or in case it's helpful for anyone else